# Безопасно ли создавать классы pyqt5 на лету?

Tags: python, qt, qt5, pyqt5

Вот такой код, работает замечательно. Не сохранятся ли лишние ссылки на объекты где-то в недрах Qt? Не потечет ли память?

```
from PyQt5.QtDBus import QDBusAbstractInterface, QDBusConnection

class Properties(QDBusAbstractInterface):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent.service(), parent.path(),
                'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties', parent.connection(), parent)

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        r = self.call('Get', self.parent().interface(), name)
        if r:
            r = r.arguments()
        if r:
            return r[0]

class BSS(QDBusAbstractInterface):
    def __init__(self, path, parent=None):
        super().__init__('fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1', path,
                'fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.BSS', QDBusConnection.systemBus(), parent)
        self.Properties = Properties(parent=self)

    @property
    def SSID(self):
        return self.Properties['SSID']

    @property
    def Signal(self):
        return self.Properties['Signal']         

class Interface(QDBusAbstractInterface):
    def __init__(self, path, parent=None):
        super().__init__('fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1', path,
                'fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.Interface', QDBusConnection.systemBus(), parent)
        self.Properties = Properties(parent=self)

    def Scan(self):
        return self.call('Scan')

    @property
    def BSSs(self):
        return [ BSS(i, self) for i in self.Properties['BSSs'] ]

class wpa_supplicant1(QDBusAbstractInterface):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__('fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1', '/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1',
                'fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1', QDBusConnection.systemBus(), parent)
        self.Properties = Properties(parent=self)

    @property
    def Interfaces(self):
        return [ Interface(i, self) for i in self.Properties['Interfaces'] ]

supplicant = wpa_supplicant1()
if supplicant.isValid():
    for ifs in supplicant.Interfaces:
        ifs.Scan()        
        for bss in ifs.BSSs:
            print(bss.SSID.data().decode(), end='\t')
            print(bss.Signal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавил я функцию в классы:

```
def __del__(self):
    print(id(self) + ' deleted')
```

И выполнилась она только при завершении программы. Надо явно вызывать деструктор если удаляешь элементы.

Если выставить `parent=None` при инициализации, то ссылка на объект всеравно  где-то висит. Но в этом случе не срабатывает деструктор при закрытии QApplication.

Буду делать singleton чтоб при перечитывании property выдавался закешированный инстанс.

Вызывать deleteLater() мне нужно для каждой BSS так как object_path (по которому будет работать singleton) увеличивается с каждым сканом. Наверное перебирать все ссылки в children после getter-а